# Is there a way to set thread priority in Glib v2.32+?

Tags: linux, multithreading, cross-platform, glib, multiplatform

Glib 2.30 [API](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Threads.html) allows setting thread priority via [GThreadPriority](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Threads.html#GThreadPriority) enum. However, that API is [deprecated as of 2.32](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.31/glib-Deprecated-Thread-APIs.html) and I can't find any info on setting thread priorities using the new API. I've Ctrl+F'd through all thread-related sections in the [API refrence](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.32/) and found nothing priority-related. Google also doesn't seem to know anything.

So is assigning priority to a thread possible in the 2.32 API at all? If yes, how to do it on creation and is it possible to change it after the thread is created? I know at that pthread supports all this, but I'd prefer to stick to the platform-independent Glib API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting thread priorities is gone. In the glib git log [this commit](http://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/commit/?id=51d92adeee67d1df30d13fe41e97af9e563f62ec) explains why

> ### GThread: deprecate thread priorities
>
> Thread priorities were already documented as not working on Solaris, and they are meaningless on Linux unless the process separately requests realtime scheduling (and even then, it appears only to work as root).

Maybe using a threadpool and the [`g_thread_pool_set_sort_function ()`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.32/glib-Thread-Pools.html#g-thread-pool-set-sort-function) could be fine ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the commit! It seems to me that  g_thread_pool_set_sort_function () will only put some threads on hold if I limit the maximum number of threads in a pool via g_thread_pool_set_max_threads (). It does not prioritize them for resource allocation or anything like that. It might be useful in some cases, though an actual prioritization would be nice. Maybe I should investigate fibers...